# How to pass an array of strings to an apple script list so the values can be iterated over on macos?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, applescript

If I have an array using swift that looks like `var array = ["james", "tom", "luke"]`

how could I convert this array into an apple script list or something that would give me the ability to use the values from the array and iterate over them with apple script.

My current code is

```
let applescriptToOpen = """
     repeat with t in \(array)
         tell application "Google Chrome"
             print value of t
         end tell
      end repeat
     """
```

A code example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AppleScript-ObjC](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC) bridge.